# Nightshifts roster example - Auto fill rest days

Tags: google-sheets

Need to implement the following and will need some hints on how to accomplish this for our hospitals' department duty roster.

If a staff member has a night shift (first 3 rows, 2-4) then on the following day a resting day should be automatically set ("//" - symbol) on the day shift rows (row >=5).

That "//" symbol should persist in the cell as long as the member is selected on a night shift row - a user should not be able to change or remove that corresponding "//".

However, when plans change and a member is deselected on the night shift row, the "//" symbol should disappear and it should then be possible to set another value on the following day shift cell.

[Here is an example sheet to play around.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X70Fmf-nLUj7UaUNcIvKC-5GCBOQVXvon9ptXN11TxM/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: sry, tried to make it as clear as possible - will modify. However, pretty simple. "//" Symbol stands for the resting day that doctors have, after they conducted a night shift. It applies to everyone on the day, the nightshift ends. So in the example you see, HOL had nightshift on the night of Fri 01 so HOL has his resting day "//" on Sat 02.

Answer (score 1):

**A14:** `={A1:AF4}`

**A18:** `={A5:B8}`

paste this into cell **C18** and drag it to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$5:$A$8, B2:B4, 1, 0), )<>"", "//", 
 REGEXREPLACE(C5:C8, "//", "")))
```

[image: 0]

**[demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X70Fmf-nLUj7UaUNcIvKC-5GCBOQVXvon9ptXN11TxM/edit#gid=1275896987)**

and then just lock down the resulting table so it couldn't be manipulated

---

or you may wanna use this instead (based on the level of security)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$5:$A$8, B2:B4, 1, 0), )<>"", "//", {C5:C8}))
```

Comment: thats a very good idea, however it should be all working within the same table.

Comment: thats not possible because you have there those dropdowns

Comment: but the dropdowns include "//"

Comment: I saw, but you cant have formula to be picked up in dropdown menu.

Comment: oh, ok, i see, well then I probably have to do a script ... thinking how to start ...